# Site not picking styles.Joomla Site deformed after moving to localhost from live server

Tags: php, joomla

I have moved my joomla website from my live server where I had hosted it to localhost.What I did is I just moved the files to directory `C:\\xampp\htdocs\mysite_folder_here`.
Thereafter I edited the configuration.php file to match the details for the localhost for example database name,server username and password.
From here I navigated to the website `127.0.0.1/mysite_folder_here` but the site I get is very deformed.It is like css for the template is not being picked.
How can I resolve this?

part my configuration.php code is :

```
public $offline = '0';
public $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance.<br /> Please check back again soon.';
public $display_offline_message = '1';
public $offline_image = '';
public $sitename = 'Micro Portal';
public $captcha = '0';
public $list_limit = '20';
public $access = '1';
public $debug = '0';
public $debug_lang = '0';
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'Colo_Coder';
public $password = '*@#CoLo?/\2016||~!CODER_100%__-#';
public $db = 'wwwyut_myportal_db';
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Joomla cache?

Comment: Have your updated the relative url of your style sheets if in case you are using any custom made template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is like css for the template is not being picked. How can I resolve
>   this?

Maybe there's a path in your template settings or CSS file, or hard-coded into your template itself which needs updating as well.

To help pinpoint this you could go to your live site, then use web inspector and look for warnings for missing files.

If this doesn't help you could temporarily change your template to Beez3 or Protostar. You can be confident that those templates are good so if you see any issues with them it's likely migration or server related.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you change the server you need to change the tmp and logs file location in configuration.php too.

Also you could simply have used [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download.html). That would have made your work more easier.

1. Check the max_execution time in your php.ini file. I keep it around 300.
2. Check if output_buffering is off.
3. Short open tags is off etc in php.ini file.

Basically during Joomla installation whatever requirements are there all should be fulfilled.